# Get value from array of JavaScript objects breaks when id is wrapped in quotes

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript code below which gets me a value from an Array of Objects using an object Key to lookup another object keys value.

JSFiddle Demo http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/h5qnwb12/

```
var selectedId = 2;

var userListArray = [
    {
      id: 0,
      image: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ed1c4f28bbd649aad6c7e1f088ecf3a2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
      name: "None"
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      image: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ed1c4f28bbd649aad6c7e1f088ecf3a2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
      name: "User 1",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      image: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ed1c4f28bbd649aad6c7e1f088ecf3a2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
      name: "User 2",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      image: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ed1c4f28bbd649aad6c7e1f088ecf3a2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
      name: "User 3",
    },
]; 

var result = userListArray.filter(function (el) {
  return el.id === selectedId;
});
var imageUrl = result[0] && result[0].image;
console.log('Image URL for User '+result[0].name+' === '+imageUrl);
```

---

The above demo works just great but in my real app my `userListArray` has my `id` values wrapped in quotes which breaks the code and makes it return `undefined`

Demo of my `id` wrapped in quotes looks like this...

```
var userListArray = [
    {
      id: "0",
      image: "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ed1c4f28bbd649aad6c7e1f088ecf3a2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
      name: "None"
    },
]
```

is there a way to make my code work when the id is wrapped in quotes?

Comment: Just change `return el.id === selectedId;` to `return el.id == selectedId;` and don't do strict comparison, problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your quote your `id` value, the below statement will return `false` as you are comparing an string to an integer.

```
return el.id === selectedId;
```

You need to change the code to:

```
return el.id === selectedId.toString();
```

Or alternatively use `==` to prevent types being compared. I have include a code example to illustrate this:

```js
var num = 0
document.write("0" === num)
document.write('<br/>')
document.write("0" == num)
document.write('<br/>')
document.write("0" === num.toString())
```

Answer (score 2):

you could cast your id to integer:

```
var result = userListArray.filter(function (el) {
  return parseInt(el.id, 10) === selectedId;
});
```

or use `~~el.id` instead of `parseInt`

Comment: I'm all for the `parseInt` approach. Using type coercion seems brittle and converting both sides to strings seems strange when the comparison is numeric (certainly from OPs POV).

Comment: However, an explicit radix of 10 can be omitted. It's 10 by default.

Comment: Sack that last comment... [MDN has in bold ***Always specify this parameter***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). The 10 should stay.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
var result = userListArray.filter(function (el) {
  return el.id == selectedId; // instead of ===
});
```

JSFiddle Upgrade: 
http://jsfiddle.net/h5qnwb12/3/

I added debug information.

This is because "3" == 3 is true, and "3" === 3 is false according to the underlying type.

You might be interested by this: [Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)